# How can I get an older package from apt-cacher-ng?

Tags: apt, apt-cacher-ng

I am trying to download a set of older `.deb` files that are no longer available from the official Ubuntu repos but are in a local cache maintained by `apt-cacher-ng`. I've added `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3142";` to my `apt.conf`, but no matter how many times I run `apt-get update`, `apt` doesn't seem to pick up the package versions I want. I even tried editing my `sources.list` to explicitly proxy the official Ubuntu repos.

As an example, I am trying to download `aptdaemon=1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1`. The official Ubuntu repos have `aptdaemon=1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19` and `aptdaemon=1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.2`. Even after pointing `apt` to the proxy, `apt-cache show aptdaemon` only shows the two versions I don't want.

Is there something I need to do to make `apt-cacher-ng` expose the package I want to `apt`?

Comment: Does `apt-cache madison aptdaemon` show all 3 versions or only the 2 from the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: It only shows the 2 from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be added as `Acquire::http { Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3142"; }` to the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy` if it exists.  If not, I think you're supposed to create the file